# Is it possible to apply a texture so that it looks like it is actually ON the mesh and not PROJECTED on?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing

So I'm working on a sci-fi piece and I have an object/mesh called "shell" which has two sides. The inside is to be textured with a wireframe texture so it looks like there is a protective mesh lining the inside of the shell.

My issue is as you see in the images. The way it unwraps the mesh the texture simply looks projected on from a particular angle instead of actually curving and following the contour of the object (as if it were really lining the surface).

Is there an unwrapping technique I am missing?

I've tried placing seams, etc, nothing looks good.

I've included two screenshots for reference.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a Hight Map node in your shader, I've seen people use the same image as both the hightmap and the texture itself, but they say it will not always work correctly.

You should and connect it to the displacement entry of the output, study a little about how to make height map images to use alongside the texture maybe.

Comment: Thanks for that info, but I do have a heightmap node. That isn't quiet the issue.

Perhaps my wording wasnt right.

the texture itself has a heightmap, diffuse, etc. It simply doesnt curve with the mesh as it would in real life.

See how the lines on the texture and the wireframe of the mesh dont curve together? As it would if the texture were REALLY lining the surface.. the straight lines of the mesh texture would become curved and not look straight. 

I feel I'm not making sense. lol

Comment: @RobertMcNatt Please add this clarification to your original post. It makes it a lot more clear :).

Answer (score 0):

To make the texture follow your object's topology, you need a rectangular UV map.
Either for the whole mesh, or just part of it.

Since I don't know what 'flow' you're looking for, here are two basic examples:

*Mesh with a projected UV map (what you have now) that keeps the texture undistorted...*

[image]

*...and with a rectangular UV map where the texture follows topology.*
[image]